# LTI standards to integrate LMS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, moodle, asp.net-mvc-5, lti

I am integrating my application in asp.net MVC with Moodle. But it need LMS standards for future integrations with any other LMS.

I am totally blank about this new term "LTI".

Answer (score 2):

Learning Tools Interoperability (LTI) is specification maintained by [IMSGlobal](https://www.imsglobal.org/activity/learning-tools-interoperability#LTIpublic)
that specifies a method for a learning system (platforms) to invoke and to communicate with external systems (tools).

The [current LTI 1.3 specification](https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti/v1p3/) is built on top of OAuth2 and OpenId Connect standards.

Answer (score 0):

please refer this link.it will help you

https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/LTI_Provider

and sample codes available in CodePlex 
http://ltisamples.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#README.txt

Comment: "Note: You are currently viewing documentation for Moodle 2.2. Up-to-date documentation for the latest stable version is available here: https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/LTI_Provider."

Answer (score 0):

LTI is a standard way of plugging in third-party tools into an LMS. Any LMS will contain a suite of tools for presenting content and assessing it (e.g., quizzes, assignments). But there are lots of other third-party tools out there that either replace the typical built-in functionality or add features not contained in it (e.g., flip cards, video embeds, different types of learning activities, etc.).

Where I work, for example, we use Blackboard Learn Ultra for our LRS. But we have the option of enhancing it with third-party tools embedded via LTI (e.g., Kaltura Media, VoiceThread, H5P).

LTI, besides allowing you to display different sorts of content, can also allow those embedded apps to communicate with the grade book. Many can also report back to the LMS in other ways, so you might have progress tracking or other analytics available to see how people interact with a particular LTI.